# Why can't I capture raw packet even though tcpdump can?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, packet-capture, raw-sockets

I'm trying to capture port-mirroring packets using raw socket (skipped error checking to show only main code):

```
int sock = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
int size = recvfrom(sock, buf, 65536, 0, &saddr, &saddr_size);
struct iphdr* iph = (struct iphdr*)(buf + sizeof(struct ethhdr));
if (iph->protocol != 6 || iph->saddr != inet_addr("192.168.12.48")) return;
printf("got it\n");
```

Although tcpdump can capture the packets, my program can't. Here's a dump of a packet:

```
22:19:42.140498 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 54, id 42987, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
192.168.12.48.33011 > 172.16.103.12.57102: Flags [.], cksum 0xf4ef (correct), ack 7, win 186, options [nop,nop,TS val 1950796524 ecr 3768292988], length 0
0x0000:  4500 0034 a7eb 4000 3606 bce3 c0a8 0c30  E..4..@.6......0
0x0010:  ac10 670c 80f3 df0e 983d f043 d1c7 3087  ..g......=.C..0.
0x0020:  8010 00ba f4ef 0000 0101 080a 7446 caec  ............tF..
0x0030:  e09b 967c                                ...|
```

I'm using CentOS 6.5 kernel 2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64. I already disabled firewall and set rp_filter to 0. Does anyone know how to capture such packets in C?

Comment: Is it possible you need to enable promiscuous mode on the interface (something that `tcpdump` does)?

Comment: You are absolutely right! After I turn on promisc I was able to receive the packets. Thanks a lot!